# adding column on dataframe using pandas library with conditions NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

currently working on python and newbie on it. I have a data frame consisting of two columns id and parent id

```
id   | parent
1    | A
2    | B
3    | C
4    | A
5    | A
6    | C
A    | NaN
B    | NaN
C    | NaN
```

And the expected output is like the table given below:

```
id   | parent | child
1    | A      | NaN
2    | B      | NaN
3    | C      | NaN
4    | A      | NaN
5    | A      | NaN
6    | C      | NaN
A    | NaN    | 1 ; 4 ; 5
B    | NaN    | 2 
C    | NaN    | 3 ; 6
```

I have tried using fillna() function on it but couldn't got expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use groupby and merge function on it.

```
print(df1)

  id parent
0  1      A
1  2      B
2  3      C
3  4      A
4  5      A
5  6      C
6  A    NaN
7  B    NaN
8  C    NaN
```

Then search their child:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('parent').agg({'id': lambda x: x.tolist()}).reset_index()
print(df2)

  parent      child
0      A  [1, 4, 5]
1      B        [2]
2      C     [3, 6]
```

finally merge them:

```
df2.columns = ['id', 'child']
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='id',how='left')
print(df3)
  id parent      child
0  1      A        NaN
1  2      B        NaN
2  3      C        NaN
3  4      A        NaN
4  5      A        NaN
5  6      C        NaN
6  A    NaN  [1, 4, 5]
7  B    NaN        [2]
8  C    NaN     [3, 6]
```